# merge same array with date index and return new array

Tags: php, arrays

My Array

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [19-05-18] => 9:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [19-05-18] => 9:00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [19-05-18] => 9:06
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [19-05-18] => 9:10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [19-05-18] => 9:10
        )
    [9] => Array
        (
            [22-05-18] => 18:23
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [22-05-18] => 18:25
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [22-05-18] => 18:25
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [22-05-18] => 18:27
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [22-05-18] => 18:27
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [22-05-18] => 18:23
        )
)
```

But I want the output like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [19-05-18] => 9:00
            [19-05-18] => 9:06
            [19-05-18] => 9:10
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [22-05-18] => 18:23
            [22-05-18] => 18:25
            [22-05-18] => 18:27
        )
)
```

Comment: Here at SO we help each other fix code, we do not write code for you. If you show us what you have tried we at least know you have made some effort and it also helps in understanding the question

Comment: I would also start by looking at how you created the original array to see if that cannot create the array as you want it rather than fiddling with the inappropriate array. Is the array created from a database query perhaps

Comment: You cant have the same key on an array

Comment: Wouldn't that make more sense as `['19-05-18' => ['9:00', '9:06', ...], ...]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$new = array();
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
        if (!isset($new[$k]))
            $new[$k] = array();

        if (!in_array($v, $new[$k])) {
            $new[$k][] = $v;
        }
    }
}
```

You could have something like this.

It will store the times in an array of arrays with the times as new indexes.
The first if statement will ensure that there are not duplicate entries. Of course, if you want duplicate entries then you are more than welcome to remove that statement from the code.

Comment: Thanks, it's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One way to group the array is using `array_reduce`

```
$arr = .... //Your array

$result = array_reduce( $arr, function( $c, $v ){
    $c[ key( $v ) ][] = current( $v );
    return $c;
}, array() );

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [19-05-18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9:00
            [1] => 9:00
            [2] => 9:06
            [3] => 9:10
            [4] => 9:10
        )

    [22-05-18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18:23
            [1] => 18:25
            [2] => 18:25
            [3] => 18:27
            [4] => 18:27
            [5] => 18:23
        )

)
```

Doc: [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

Comment: Thanks, it's really helpful.

Comment: Happy to help @RanaHaseeb